# Powershell script to run for certain files on a network drive

Tags: powershell

I'm pretty new to Powershell and I'm looking for assistance on creating a script.

I need to run a script to look for 6 file extensions on a Network Drive Folder and subfolder and put into a csv list with the file name and path.

So it would be for x:\Sample Data and all subfolders under that.  The file extensions are .las, .lax, .gdb , .dwg, .dxf, .dgn, .shp

Any assistance or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Lookup [Get-ChildItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) and read about its parameters `-Recurse` and `-Include`

Comment: Thank you Theo, I will do that

Comment: @Theo OK,  I did this Get-ChildItem -Path 'X:\Sample Data' -Recurse -Include *.las, *.lax, *.gdb, *.dwg, *.dwg, *.dxf, *.dgn, *.shp

$List |ft fullname |out-file C:\Powershell\report.csv   but when the report is generated, nothing is shown in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close!

Try

```
$includes = '*.las', '*.lax', '*.gdb', '*.dwg', '*.dxf', '*.dgn', '*.shp'
Get-ChildItem -Path 'X:\Sample Data' -Recurse -File -Include $includes |
Select-Object @{Name = 'Path'; Expression = { $_.FullName }} |
Export-Csv -Path 'C:\Powershell\report.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Since you are only storing one property, you might also want to consider saving as simple text file:

```
$includes = '*.las', '*.lax', '*.gdb', '*.dwg', '*.dxf', '*.dgn', '*.shp'
(Get-ChildItem -Path 'X:\Sample Data' -Recurse -File -Include $includes).FullName |
Set-Content -Path 'C:\Powershell\report.txt'
```

Comment: Hi @Theo, when I ran the top one you kindly provided, I get the following                Get-ChildItem : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'File'.
At line:2 char:47
+ Get-ChildItem -Path 'X:\Sample Data' -Recurse -File -Include $include ...

Comment: @britman71 What version of PowerShell are you running? You could leave it out, but then you risk that directories also get enumerated. On old powershell (< 3.0) you need to pipe to `| Where-Object { !$_.PsIsContainer }` as extra step after Get-ChildItem instead of using switch `-File`.

Comment: @britman71 You can see your version by typing `$PSVersionTable` Then look at the PSVersion value,

Comment: Hi @Theo. I'm on PS 5.1  I tried it as you suggested and it ran.  However, still nothing showed in the csv file when completed.  I can see the results scrolling thru though

Comment: @britman71 I just tested again and couldn't find anything wrong with the code. Both versions run absolutely fine and the output files are correct.. How are you running this? Are you sure you are looking at the correct output file? Do you have that file blocked in any way perhaps? Getting error messages?

Comment: thanks for the follow up.  I did run it again and it worked as it should.  Not sure why it didn't yesterday.  Many thanks for the help and teaching!

Comment: @britman71 Thanks for verifying! If you find my answer solved your problem, please consider marking the question 'done' by clicking the large checkmark icon on the left of the answer. This will help others with a similar question finding it more easily.